# Is hashbang in URL still SEO friendly in 2018?

Tags: seo, url, hash

I have seen old posts that say you can make sure your website is crawled by Google crawlers if you add `#!` in it. E.g. `www.example.com/guns#!colt`.

But those posts are way old from 2014. And I've also heard Google has removed support for such URLs being crawled. And now I am confused, can someone say for sure how I can get fragments to be detected by crawlers?

Comment: Is your site using Ajax or some other JavaScript to load content?

Comment: No it is really a weird requirement. I can't explain.